# Issues while Using Maven with Android Dx

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I'm having a lot of issues while trying tu create a project using Maven and Eclipse.
It randomly shows me the following message:

```
[2014-03-20 16:36:40 - App] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2014-03-20 16:36:40 - App] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-03-20 16:36:40 - App] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

And when I say it's Randomly, it's really Random, few minutes ago I was running the project just fine, and now, that thing it's appearing.

I don't know what is happening, because I don't event use QName.class.

Do you know what is happening???

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you please post your POM?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the **Maven android plug-in** or **m2e-android** you need to be careful about your dependencies: it look as though you have a transitive dependency that includes the `javax.xml.*` pacakage which is, if you read the error message, illegal for Dalvik compilation.

Solution: find the transitive dependency and [exclude it in your POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I was developing some Libraries using the Android Dependencies that made that awful error. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my late response:

When I was developing this part of the project, I created also some libraries, but there were more like a **DataAccess** library or **Model** library so Instead of creating an *Android Project* I created a Simple ***Java Library Project*** for I was using only some of the Android API such as Context for **DataAccess** and another ones for **Model**, well on my **pom.xml** i didn't exclude the ***Android Jars*** so that Created the Conflict.

Just in case somebody do the same thing...

Thank You!!